# How to create a folder inside a folder using laravel

Tags: laravel-4

In new in laravel.
I trying to  create a folder inside a folder using laravel.I want to  create a new folder inside the another folder .what is the html code for blade.php page.

Answer (score 1):

> you can use File::makeDirectory to create folder inside folder

```
$path = public_path().'/uploads/test';
File::makeDirectory($path,0777, true, true);
```

List All Directory for user **john**

> 1. main directory **john_1**
>
>    1.1 john has 3 sub directory **abc**,**xyz** and **mno**
> 2. get all directory of user john and pass it view from controller

```
 $list = File::directories('/john_1');
 return View::make('upload',array('list'      => $list));
```

> 3. finally display it as selectbox

```
{{ Form::select('folder_name', $list, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

> 4. list all image from user john

```
foreach (File::allFiles(public_path().'/john_1/img/') as $file) {
     $filename = $file->getRelativePathName();

     echo HTML::image('public/john_1/img/'.$filename, $filename); 
}
```

> This will attempt to create /uploads if it doesn't exist. Then
>   /uploads/test if it doesn't exist.If all created directories are
>   successfully created then true will be returned.

Comment: is it  contoller.php code .... ok i want blade.php code? how to insert a new folder from webpage. ..if we can insert a new file usinghtml code is here (<input type="file" name="f"> .now like this what is the html code for insert new folder..

Comment: i don't think you can create folder using html code or blade template you need some server side scripting to create folder on server not client side scripting language

Comment: oh..is its not possible?? i have a doubt...if one user can need create a new folder into our webpage and upload images into that folders..how tis possible??? now i want develop a web page that contain 1.add folder...2.insert image name.(textbox)  3.select folder(dorp down)  and 4.upload image. what is the html or blade template code??

Comment: Okay. what you can you is such case create main directory by user(let's say user barkamlesh and uid:1 than directory name would be barkamlesh_1 when user register) and allow user to create directory within his/her main folder and you can get list of all directory created by him using syntax $list = File::directories('/barkamlesh_1'); you can create main directory name anything you want but it should be unique

Comment: do want to create directory by user or some public directory for all? By user i mean when user login he can only access his directory to choose and upload image. or public directory where every one can access same directory and create their own.

Comment: okk....but user can create 2 folder to public folder.how can display thses 2 floders  in dropdown(list box) and how can select one folder..,how to upload image into that folder?? if you dont mine can you explain code for it...

Comment: i have another doubt...how to view(display) that user folders and also images to webpage???what is code for it???

Comment: for display all folder by user you can see point 3 and for display image from that folder i have added code point 4.

Comment: you can upvote/accept  if it helped. you should also edit your profile and personal info it will be helpful four your career

Comment: sir,,im trying to insert image from webpage to database and selected folder using this conrtoller.php code  else
       {   
      $f1=Input::get('f1');
            $path ='img/uploads/'.$f1;
          File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
             $file=Input::file('galimg');
            $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
           $file->move('img/uploads/'.$f1,$filename);
              ForumGallery::create([
             'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
             'galimg'=>$f1.'/'.$filename
              ]);  but not working...how to insert image database and folder?

Comment: are you trying to upload image name into database not image right?

Comment: image name only upload into database..but image is not save into folder?? im using  2 <from>tag in blade.php it is possible??????

Comment: add params files =>true in form tag {{Form::open(array('method' => 'POST','url'=>'home/create-todo','files'=> true, 'id' =>'createEventForm'))}}

Comment: Im using this code {{ Form::select('folder_name', $list, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }} not working...can you say html code <select><option></option></select> get the value from $list.. then im use <select  name="f1" class="form-control">
        <option value="{{$list}}">{{$list}}</option>
      </select> i got  an error  ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sb\app\views\gallery\addnewgallery.blade.php) how solve it Iwant <select >tag.

Comment: now using this code {{ Form::select('folder_name', $list, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }} i can select folder but click submit another folder is created and image is save into that folder..not in selected folder..using controller.php is  $f1=Input::get('f1');
        
             $file=Input::file('galimg');
            $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName(); //save img name into database
           $file->move($f1,$filename); 
              ForumGallery::create(['galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
             'galimg'=>$f1.'/'.$filename  ]);